# Spring Expression Language (SpEL) access locale in Repository Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-el

I need to access current locale in Spring Repository using SpEL.

I have next `Repository`:

```java
@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<Room, Long> {

    @Query(..."left join rc.roomClassTranslations rct on rct.language = ?#{SpEL expression})
    List<RoomDTO> findAllRooms(Sort sort);
}
```

I tried several expressions but none of them worked.

`#{@localeResolver.resolveLocale(#httpServletRequest).toLanguageTag()} "...)` In this expression httpServletRequest is null, if I change it to `@httpServletRequest`, it will give an error that no bean is found. I also tried to rewrite it like this

`#{LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().toLanguageTag()}` this will give next error:

> EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getLocale() on null
> context object.

So how to access current locale in SpEL expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring support the usage of **[restricted SpEL template expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions) in manually defined queries that are defined with `@Query`.**

Spring Data exposes an extension point [`EvaluationContextExtension`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/spel/spi/EvaluationContextExtension.html).

Spring Data JPA will pick up all beans of type `EvaluationContextExtension` and use those to prepare the `EvaluationContext` to be used to evaluate the **SpEL expression defined in `@Query`.**

###### Let's implement the locale extension as an example.

```java
@Component
public class LocaleEvaluationContextExtension
        implements EvaluationContextExtension {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(
                EvaluationContextExtension.super.getProperties());
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "locale";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRootObject() {
        return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    }
}
```

###### The query method definition should be:

```java
@Query(..."left join rc.roomClassTranslations rct on " +
        "rct.language = ?#{locale.language})
List<RoomDTO> findAllRooms(Sort sort);
```