# Can I use a @RequestParam as a @Query parameter when using Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm using **Spring Data Rest**, my `Repository` extends `JpaRepository` and I want to create a custom query with `@Query`.

My method parameter is a `@RequestParameter` and I want to use it as a parameter for the query:

```java
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :search")
List<User> findBySearch(@RequestParam("search") @Param("search") String search);
```

Can I use the `@RequestParam` as parameter for the query?

Comment: Curious to know, if you tried your approach.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is the variable that is defined in a functional block. So, it is basically used whenever we need to pass a value to a particular functional block.

*Depending on this;* even if you could use `@RequestParam`, you would have to send this value when you call this method.

I'm not sure that getting the value using this is what you want.

##### You can try to get the request parameter directly:

> Spring support the usage of **restricted SpEL template expressions**
> in manually defined queries that are defined with `@Query`.

You can create custom `EvaluationContextExtension` to use [request parameters directly in @Query.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650177/2039546)

```java
@Component
public class RequestEvaluationContextExtension
        implements EvaluationContextExtension {

    private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    public RequestEvaluationContextExtension(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(
                EvaluationContextExtension.super.getProperties());
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "request";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRootObject() {
        return httpServletRequest;
    }
}
```

Usage in query should be like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name  = ?#{request.getParameter('search')}")
List<User> findBySearchParameter();
```

You can call this repository method without sending any arguments.

If your http request has a `search` parameter *(eg: `http://localhost:8080/test?search=foobar`)* You create a query based on the value of this parameter.